Why is the connection (covariant derivative) with all the Christoffel symbols as 0 not metric compatible?
If we consider a covariant derivative where all the Christoffel symbols are zero it will not really rotate a vector as it parallel transports it between tangent vector spaces. Therefore, angles between vectors and their magnitudes seem like they should be preserved and yet this connection is not metric compatible. I can see why this is through algebra but why is this so geometrically/intuitively?

It is certainly metric compatible some times, such as in Euclidean space with Cartesian coordinates.

The vectors may not change, but the metric might. Say the metric coefficients become larger as you move away from your point. Then, the vector with the same components will also grow in size as you move along.

Not definitive, but because holonomy

@AndrewD.Hwang This was the answer I was looking for, thanks!
